# How to initialize the state of a class using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

My task is to print out the list of files in the current directory.
Here is my current code:

```
class StringSet {
    private String[] ss;

    File currentDirectory = new File(".");
    File[] dirFiles = currentDirectory.listFiles();

    public StringSet() {
        StringToFile(0, dirFiles.length);
       

    }

    public void StringToFile(int start, int end) {
        /*ss = new String[dirFiles.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dirFiles.length; i++) {
            if (dirFiles[i].isFile())
                ss[i] = dirFiles[i].getPath();
        }
    }*/
        ss = new String[dirFiles.length];
        if (start == end)
            return;

        if (dirFiles[start].isFile())
            ss[start] = dirFiles[start].getPath();

        StringToFile(start + 1, end);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s="";
        for (int i=0; i<ss.length; i++)
            if (ss[i]!=null)
                s+=ss[i]+"\n";
        if (s.length()>0)
            s = s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
        return s;
    }
```

The `for` loop that I commented here, produces the desired result of assigning the current directory's pathnames to `ss[i]`. The `toString()` method works off of that and produces all of the filenames. The uncommented code depicts the recursive approach, however it does not seem to be assigning the pathnames to `ss` like the `for` loop does, unless I specifically add a `println()` in the method, which isn't what I want. It produces nothing. How would I make it achieve the same effect as the for loop?

Comment: Your loop re-assigns the `ss` variable each time through, blowing away all of your work from the previous call. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It makes sense now why I kept getting nothing. I removed that statement and initialized ss in the constructor instead and that did the trick.